# Getting "Couldn't find that app." when trying to create new Postgres DB in Heroku

Tags: postgresql, heroku, command-line-interface

I am trying to upgrade from hobby dev tier to hobby basic tier on Heroku in order to continue using Heroku before they cancel all the free plans.

A developer I had hired a while back set up the db via Hasura- well at least Hasura is used to manage the database. (Not sure if that info is necessary but trying to give as much of the background as possible.) Anyway,  he is no longer available, but I have some modicum of dev skills, so am attempting to do this on my own.

Apparently, I need to use the `pg:copy` method according to the doc at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/upgrading-heroku-postgres-databases#upgrading-with-pg-copy. (Why they didn't make it easy with a simple button click and a credit card on their website is beyond me. But, according to their CEO, "It's not that simple.")

So... I installed the Heroku CLI on Windows. (This is actually a parallels VM I am running on my Mac.) I also installed git in the VM per the installation instructions.

Now I am getting stuck on the first step of creating the new db.

I entered:

```
heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql:hobby-basic --app new-db-app --version 13.8
```

And got back:

```
 »   Warning: heroku update available from 7.53.0 to 7.65.0.
Creating heroku-postgresql:hobby-basic on ⬢ new-db-app... !
 !    Couldn't find that app.
```

I tried initializing git with `git init`. But got the same error. I also tried

```
git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:new-db-app.git
```

for good measure but that didn't help.

I tried to upgrade the CLI and ran heroku update and got back:

```
heroku: Updating CLI from 7.53.0 to 7.65.0... !
Error: SHA mismatch: expected 54e926b1363d71a28f9436f732860cc000126ca131ccb2ca59f05b701fb6d0ce to be 94b066001386392123fe79b634f706e236143906f61751c4e85d3400fb4af2d7
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:/Program Files/heroku/client/node_modules/@oclif/plugin-update/lib/tar.js:32:32)
```

But, I ran it again and it worked.

However, this did not alleviate my issue. I still got the dreaded "Couldn't find that app."

What am I doing wrong? I suspect it has to do with git.

But it is not even creating the app. When I run heroku apps I just see the original one.

Any nudge in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. (BTW I tried to create a ticket directly with Heroku, but their system only accepts tickets for paid plans.  It's a maddening catch-22 that does not endear me to Heroku, which is putting it rather mildly.)

Thanks!

Comment: Heroku problems almost never have anything to do with Git. Heroku simply uses Git as a transportation mechanism for commits: you send the commit to Heroku, Heroku reads and analyzes it, and decides whether or not it likes that particular commit and instructs Git to accept or reject the `git push`, and that's all that Git has to do with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I entered:
>
> ```
> heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql:hobby-basic --app new-db-app --version 13.8
> ```

The argument for `--app` should be the name of the existing Heroku app to attach the new database to. It's not a name for the database itself.

You can see the names of the apps you have by [running `heroku apps`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands#heroku-apps).

Comment: And if you see it in the console, but not in the list, you're probably logged in as the wrong Heroku user.

Comment: Thank you Chris. That was it.  And Thanks ceejayoz as well!

Comment: Incidentally, I learned you also need to copy the db to a new add-on in the same app, not create a new app. I tried that at first and wasn't able to get the "color url" of the new db, likely because I only had one add-on for the new app.